# jquery event to set css

Tags: jquery, css, tagging

hey i have a jquery easy ui on my page.. but i little confuse here... i want to create a input field but the looks is like some kind of tagging field, so after the user type the separator character (lets say comma) , then the word was typing will have their css like tagging field...

anybody can suggest me where must i go??

i was looking everywhere but i am still confused..

i will really appreciate it if you can help me to do this... i really need this code... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for one of these:

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

or

http://webspirited.com/tagit/

Comment: Yes, just customize the input field as you like. In my experience, i had a lot of trouble with callback method there. So, it's not very suitable if you want to get auto suggested values.